# How to run invisible subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I would like to know if it's possible to run Python application subprocess in such way that there wouldn't be duplicate process in task manager?

Answer (score 5):

Not without getting into subversive process hiding tasks.

If as a user that wants to look at the running processes, let me see the running processes. Don't hide it from me.

Techniques to hide running processes may also be picked up by some anti virus as potential threats.

Don't do it.

Actually, why do you want to? I can't think of a single reason to hide a process for a legit program.

Comment: I am working on a GUI application and I want it to have multiple windows. For example if you create a new window in Opera there's no duplicate process. That's what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: They probably aren't creating a new process at all. They are probably just creating a separate window. Google chrome actually creates separate processes for each tab that can all be viewed by task manager.

Comment: what GUI library are you using?

Comment: Opera most surely has multiple threads running which is what you would want to do. In task manager you should be able to see the thread count associated with the process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this "subprocess" needs to actually be a process?  Maybe you could do the work inside of a thread instead of forking a new process.  I'm not sure if that would accomplish your goals though, since you're not specific about what you need multiple processes for.